# What function is used to iterate through a list of lists and only print specific rows to the console?

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, module

For the last part of a Python assignment, I need to iterate through the lists of lists and print to the console the rows with category 'Hardware'.  This is the csv file:

```
Hardware,Hammer,10,10.99
Hardware,Wrench,12,5.75
Food,Beans,32,1.99
Paper,Plates,100,2.59
```

The following is the code for the last part, which simply opens the file to be read and passed into a list:

```
def read_text():

    with open("products.csv", "r", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        temp_prod = list(reader)
```

I'm having an issue with coding the right for loop to pull out the 'Hardware' rows.  Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to repeat your materials on working with lists (and strings).  Look for the `in` operator.  Use something like `if "Hardware" in row`, where `row` is a single row/list of your file.

Comment: Pardon me, but did you read my question?  I wasn't looking to replace anything.  Just the correct for loop or search function that will pull out the two rows I want and print them to the console.  I have read documentation and at this time it is not making it clear to me, hence why I sought help here.  Thank You!

Comment: Yes, I read your question.  You don't know how to write a loop or comprehension on a file.  You don't know how to write a filter.  These items are covered well by documentation and examples on the web.  Therefore, teaching you these things is appropriate for a tutorial or local tutor -- not Stack Overflow.  See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: As you are reading everything at once, try something like `hardware = list(zip(*temp_prod))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

When you are stuck, try to do a lot of printing to see what is going on. You were in a good point. `temp_prod` gave you a list of lists. You have to iterate through this list of list and ask if the first item is equal to your search criteria.

You code should look like that:

```
def read_text(my_file):
    import csv
    with open(my_file, "r", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        temp_prod = list(reader)
        for row in temp_prod:
            if row[0] == "Hardware":
                print(row)
```

Call the function that way:

```
read_text("filepath.csv")
```

Please note that this function (as you requested) **doesn't return anything, it only prints.**